# Cursor doesn't fetch values correctly in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is the table that I wanna fetch info from:

```
CREATE TABLE public.insurance_premiums (
    contract_code text NOT NULL,
    insurance_team text NOT NULL,
    starting_date date NOT NULL,
    expiration_date date NOT NULL,
    contract_cost float8 NOT NULL,
    vehicle_contract text NOT NULL,
    customer_contract text NOT NULL,
    driver_contract text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT insurance_premiums_pkey PRIMARY KEY (contract_code)
);
```

Here is the **Cursor**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_info (s_d_1 DATE, s_d_2 DATE)
RETURNS TABLE (
    contract_code text,
    customer_contract text,
    driver_contract text
) AS $$
    declare
    new_contract record;
    code text;
    customer text;
    driver text;

    new_contract_cursor CURSOR (s_d_1 DATE, s_d_2 DATE) FOR
        select insurance_premiums.contract_code, insurance_premiums.customer_contract, insurance_premiums.driver_contract 
        from public.insurance_premiums 
        where starting_date >= s_d_1 and starting_date <= s_d_2;
        
        begin
            
            open new_contract_cursor(s_d_1, s_d_2);
            
            loop
                fetch new_contract_cursor into new_contract;
                exit when not found;
                code := new_contract.contract_code;
                customer := new_contract.customer_contract;
                driver := new_contract.driver_contract;
                return next;
            end loop;
    
            close new_contract_cursor;
    
        end;$$ language plpgsql;
```

**Note**: s_d_1 stands for starting_date_1 same goes for s_d_2.

Here is also the simple **SELECT** query:

```
select insurance_premiums.contract_code, insurance_premiums.customer_contract, insurance_premiums.driver_contract from public.insurance_premiums 
where starting_date >= '2021/06/01' and starting_date <= '2021/06/30';
```

This `SELECT` query fetches the correct data from the table. It simply returns **2 rows** with **3 columns** that are all **text**.

The cursor on the other hand, even though it creates a new table and **correctly** fetches **2 rows** and **3 columns** all the data is **NULL** instead of **text**.

I'm guessing that something is wrong inside the **loop** or in the `select` query inside the cursor.

I also thought about the fact that I create a new table with **column names** being the **same** from the table I fetch might have to do anything. I don't think this is it but you never know.

Comment: Why use a cursor and a slow and inefficient (nested) loop or even PL/pgSQL for this? This can easily be done with a single SELECT statement

Comment: I'm just learning Cursors so I wanted to test it with a simple example query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assigned anything to the output parameters, so the output consists of nulls.  For example, an output parameter is "customer_contract", but you assign to "customer", which is a variable which seems to serve no purpose.